# "Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'String'" compiler error when trying to access returned string from closure

Tags: swift, closures, urlsession

```
func requestList(completionParameter: @escaping (String) -> String ) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.de")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            let message = error.localizedDescription
            completionParameter(message)
        }
        if let response = response {
            let message = response.mimeType!
            completionParameter(message)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func printer() -> String {
    let dspmsg = requestList(completionParameter: { message1 -> String in
        let t = type(of: message1)
        print(t)
        return message1
        })
    return dspmsg
```

The returned value for `dspmsg` is `Void` apparently, but when I check the contents of `message1` inside the closure `completionParameter` for `requestList`, I always get the expected text, and that it is of type `String`. Before using that `printer()` function I tried to print the return from the closure directly, which led me to the same error.

My goal is to request website data and use it outside of the closure.

My suspicion is that the return in `printer()` happens before `completionParameter` has finished.
But as I have stated, directly printing the return and circumventing the timing problem, prints an empty tuple, which as I understand is equal to `Void`.

Comment: You can't convert an asynchronous method into a synchronous method.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/

Comment: After reading your replies I realized that I was on the right track when I was talking about timing. I read up on asynchronicity and I think I only now start to realize how much actually changes; for example even the print statement didn't wait for the async code to finish.
I fixed my issue now by removing the printer function and using onAppear in my Textfield and moving the requestList function with its completionParameter into it.

Comment: Also, that "programmingios" site explains the issue really really well in my opinion, thanks for that link!

Comment: More specifically the problem in your code is that the function that returns the string is not the function that you call. `requestList` returns Void (equivalent to () ) and you pass to `requestList` a closure that will be executed later and will returns a string. Hence your confusion. And hence the error message `Cannot convert () to String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Async/Await Concurrency in Swift. You can try something like:

1. Create an async method and use URLSession async method `data(from: URL)`

---

```
func requestList() async -> String {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.de")!
    do {
        let (_, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        guard let mime = response.mimeType else {
            throw URLError(.unknown)
        }
        return mime
    } catch {
       return error.localizedDescription
    }
}
```

---

2. Declare your printer method as async as well:

---

```
func printer() async -> String {
    let dspmsg = await requestList()
    print(dspmsg)
    return dspmsg
}
```

3. Then you can call it using await

---

```
Task {
    let string = await printer() // text/html
}
```

Comment: This answer together with the articles that were linked helped me resolve my issue.